# Hidden php error (facebook api)

Tags: php, html, facebook-graph-api

I'm having some trouble with the facebook api. When i run this code, all i see on the website is the html before , but if i remove the php i can see the whole site.

I'm relativly new to php, and i've stared at the code for almost a half hour now

here is the code:

```
<head>

    <title>Written And Seen</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

</head>

<body>

    <?php 

    include 'libs/Facebook.php';


    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => '5000...458', //the dots are not the problem. i just replaced part of the id/secret when posting here
        'secret' => '8fe...e5',
        'cookie' => true
    ));         
    $session = $facebook->getSession();     
    $me = null;     
    if ($session){      
        try{            
            $me = $facebook->api('/me');            
        }
        catch (FacebookApiException $e){            
            echo $e->getMessage();              
        }   
    }       
    if($me){        
        $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

    }

    else{

        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();

    }
    ?>

    <div id="allcontent">       
        <div id="header">
            <h1 style="text-align:center;">Written And Seen</h1>
        </div>          
        <div id="navigation">           
            <a href="#">Home</a><a href="#">Adasdasda</a><a href="#">HFgsdfs</a><a href="#">HFgsdfs</a><a href="#">Log in with Facebook</a>         
        </div>          
        <div id="maincontent">                                  
        </div>          
        <div id="footer">           
        </div>          
    </div>          
</body>
```

Comment: run it fron cli and see whats going on, probably your include failed and then Facebook class not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm relativly new to php

We all were once ;)

You need access to your error reporting, it's paramount if you're coding PHP as it'll tell you what you did wrong (though not perfectly, some knowledge/common sense is still to be applied)
It will tell you, for example, "unable to include 'libs/Facebook.php'" so you can then check your paths, where the file is etc. Or report an unexpected character (ie missing or extra semi colon, comma, braces, etc)

Also, (unrelated but to help) if you get errors or something simply just doesn't work as expected, echo out variables etc to see what PHP sees, this can often point out the issue (empty variable you thought should be set etc) and can trace back from there

Answer (score 0):

Starring is not enough in most cases ;)

Enable error reporting by using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on next line after `<?php`. Then you should see what is going on.

Comment: if i look at the source i see this:





<html>

 <head>
 
  <title>Written And Seen</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
 
 </head>
 
 <body>

Comment: @Pownyan You should read this http://pl1.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php